# Error codes for UserAccount_Profile_Create on Buddy

Tags: asp.net-mvc, buddy.com

Using www.buddy.com (The Buddy Platform) for an ASP.NET MVC app.

The docs for `UserAccount_Profile_Create` are not clear on what passed information can be duplicate across users.  The error code `UserNameAlreadyInUse` is obvious, and the docs say `all user names must be unique in the system`.  But what about email addresses?

What if I WANT email addresses to be unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The platform does not enforce unique emails as you noticed, but you can enforce this in your app. We have a [API to check for a existing email](http://buddy.com/APIDocumentation/DocHome.aspx?Topic=UserAccount_Profile_CheckUserEmail) , you can use this to enforce a password policy per application.